# Clojure: single machine, Clojure <-> ClojureScript, Ring, websocket communication

Tags: clojure

### Context

I like Clojure. I like Clojure more than I like ClojureScript.

I like the DOM more than I like Swing.

I intend to build a GUI application mainly in Clojure, but using a web browser's DOM as for the GUI. [I have tried JavaFX, it crashes on me, often, I don't like it.]

Now, I'm familiar with ring + ajax requests + setup web socket once. What I want to know is -- what is the lowest latency setup I can come up with?

Both the client (web browser) and server (clojure stuff) run on the same machine. I have root access on the machine. I just want merely to setup the minimal latency communication channel.

### Question:

How do I setup minimal latency communication between clojurescript / clojure when I have full control over the machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websockets (the fastest two-way method supported by modern browsers) on localhost (which on most reasonable platforms uses shared memory IPC or similar avoiding most of the network stack alltogether).